# What are pros and cons of using large CSS files?

Tags: html, css, performance

Let's say I create 100 selectors inside style.css with a following pattern:

```
.width-1 {width: 1%;}
.width-2 {width: 2%;}
/* up to... */
.width-100 {width: 100%;}
```

Also do the same with height, table of colors and include many other styles. The final result might be a css file containing about 5000 selectors and taking 300kB of size.

**The question is:** Why should or shouldn't I do this? Will too many selectors cause performance issues?

**Pros:**

- One large css file requires only one http request,
- I can load a lot of css features for every website, just in case,

**Cons:**

- Obviously - large css file size,
- IE 8-9 can contain only 4095 selectors max in one css file,
- There is a risk of loading too many styles which won't be used on current view.

I'm interested in targeting Android 2.3+ and IE8+

Comment: minify a css and add gzip compression for text/css mimetype

Comment: If you're going to make a selector just for every percentage value from 1 to 100% you might as well just use an inline style where you need it. If you have predefined widths that you want to use (ie. 12.5%, 25%, 37.5%, etc.) then create some classes.

Comment: if you target android, you must not be having that large css file, dont worry about IE, you will not even get close to  4095

Comment: and you yourself have answered within the question

Comment: Not quite sure why you would want a file with 1% changes for widths and heights. Are you really expecting the site you build to have elements positioned statically at each combination of those values? If not then only produce a CSS file with the values you use. If you're thinking of doing a calculation in script but then applying the correct combinations of styles to match your calculated values - you could just apply the values directly from script without the need for adding a class..

Answer (score 0):

The one large file thing isn't too bad. That's why we minify/concatenate our stuff into single files. The problem is when you're using that many utility classes and a lot of them won't be used. Every selector will make the browser look up all elements of that class. So that's a whole lot of (worthless) checking to see if something's there.

If you want to have a whole bunch of utility styled things for easy usage you should consider making some mixins in sass or less. That way your css won't contain as many unused / useless content (and selectors).

So I wouldn't say that the filesize is bad, it's more the extreme slowness and uselessness of the selectors you're showing.

Comment: At the end of a day sass files are compiled into css which uses the same amount of selectors as pure Css file.

Comment: No, the mixins would only add to the size of your file if you use it. My suggestion is to not add all of those classes to a css file because they make no sense. Instead a mixin would output a width in % where needed. So that's less selectors in your css because the styling is on a more useful selector

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously stupid to add each and every width, height, color and more to a separate class each. That's is just a workaround for inline CSS. You might as well just use inline CSS and everyone will be better off.

To answer your question: 
using a large CSS-file can have big performance issues. 
using many CSS files might not be be an option too. iOS supports only a limited number of included CSS files per document. (I can't find the reference

Conclusion: don't. Do like everyone else and define a style for a specific class like CSS was meant to be.